# Should I repot these orchids

Tags: orchids, repotting

About a year ago I got this orchid as a present. There are two separate plants in a single pot. They were blooming when I bought them, then bloomed a second time. The larger orchid bloomed first by a few weeks. The pictures are of the third bloom for the smaller orchid. The larger orchid hasn't bloomed a third time, and is instead growing these air roots. It's also tilted quite a bit to the north (I have a N-E corner kitchen with glass block walls, which generates a lot of diffuse light. The shoots tend to point North). The pot has drainage, I water it about once every 7-10 days, adding Orchid fertilizer roughly once a month.

I'm debating splitting them up into two pots, as the air roots and lack of bloom are concerning to me. If that's the way to go, should I wait for the smaller orchid to finish blooming, or am I hurting the larger one in the process?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These plants are [Moth orchids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalaenopsis) or Phalaenopsis.  They don't actually need soil as they are [epiphytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyte). The air roots are a sign of a healthy plant.

The plants have not been in the pot that long and can probably go a few more years.  Your next pot should have a free draining mix including shredded bark.

Your watering and fertilizer regime are working well as the plants look in very good health. Repotting would not necessarily mean more blooms and might cause the orchids to spend more energy on growing new roots.

I recommend rotating the plant weekly so it does not continue to grow to one side.